# JQuery not working in my plugin

Tags: plugins, jquery, javascript

This is my first time using JQuery in a WordPress plugin, and I'm having some trouble.

Here is my "main" plugin document:

```
<?php

/*
    Plugin Name: Dump-It Scheduler
    Plugin URI: 
    Description:Description
    Version: 1.0
    Author: Blaine Anderson
    Author URI: http://www.blainevanderson.net
    License: 

*/

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'load_jquery' );
add_action('wp_register_script', 'register_script');
add_action('wp_enqueue_script', 'run_js_script');
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_master_schedule'); 
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_customer_search'); 
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_edit_trucks');
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_new_customer'); 

//Add master schedule link to Admin bar in WP
function add_master_schedule()
{
    add_menu_page('Master Schedule', 'Master Schedule', 'administrator', 'Master_Dump-it_Schedule', 'display_menu'); 
}

//Display the master schedule when link is clicked
function display_menu()
{
    include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/Views/admin_main_display.php');
}

//Add customer search link to admin bar
function add_customer_search()
{
    add_menu_page('Customer Search', 'Customer Search', 'administrator', 'Customer_Search', 'display_customer_search');
}

//Display customer search page
function display_customer_search()
{
    include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/Views/search_customer.php');
}

//Add edit trucks link to admin bar
function add_edit_trucks()
{
    add_menu_page('Edit Trucks', 'Edit Trucks', 'administrator', 'Display_Edit_Trucks', 'display_edit_trucks');
}

//Display edit trucks page when link is clicked.
function display_edit_trucks()
{
    include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/Views/edit_trucks.php');
}

//Add 'add customer' link to admin bar
function add_new_customer()
{
    add_submenu_page('Customer_Search', 'Add Customer', 'Add Customer', 'administrator', 'Add_Customer', 'display_add_customer');
}

//Display add customer page when link is clicked.
function display_add_customer()
{
    include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/Views/add_customer.php'); 
}

//Load jquery into plugin
function load_jquery() 
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}

function run_js_script()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('my_plugin_script'); 
}
function register_script()
{
    wp_register_script( 'my_plugin_script', plugins_url('/js/scheduler.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', false);
}
?>
```

Here is my Javascript that simply displays an alert (scheduler.js):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    alert("Hello World!");
});
```

I'm wondering why the alert isn't showing up. I've also tried to add the `wp_enqueue_script` to the `HTML` file, which  looks like this:

```
<?php
wp_enqueue_script( 'my_plugin_script' );
?>

<table width="100%" id="menubar">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="" onclick="display_customer_search();">Master Schedule</a> | <a href=truckroutes.php>Create Truck Routes</a> | <a href="search.php">Customer Search</a> | <a href="trucks.php">Edit Trucks</a> | <a href="customeredit.php?id=new">Add Customer</a> | <a href="/cms/login.php">CMS Login</a> | </td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm very new to WordPress and any direction or help would be appreciated. If you need any other code, please let me know, but that is most of it. The only other code I have is the views for the other links.

Comment: The action is [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts), plural. also see the dependencies argument of the [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function.

Comment: @Milo: **comments** != **answers** ;)

Comment: @toscho I'm a little confused how posting code that isn't working is considered "off-topic". Closing things like this will make me think twice about using this site again. Of course having specific code issues are going to local, but isn't that the point of this site? Getting help with code?

Comment: @Blaine Typos are off topic, not code. :)

Comment: @toscho, it wasn't a typo. I didn't realize that I there was a difference between the 2 methods. If you had read my entire post you would have seen the part where I said, "I'm very new to Wordpress...". I'll also add that I don't agree with the "typos are off topic". We all make mistakes and sometimes need a second set of eyes. We all miss `;` at times or spell something wrong. I would think that this is exactly what the site is for: helping others.

Comment: Mistyped names are off topic, because otherwise our site would be flooded by those questions which don’t help anyone else. If you think we should change our scope, ask a question on [meta].

Comment: @toscho, thanks but no. If you think that not knowing the difference between the 2 is off-topic, then I will find another site to use. You call it a typo, I call it a lack of understanding. I deliberately used that method, and it was wrong. I find it hard to believe that I'm the only one who has ever done this, or ever will. Thank you for your response. Good day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an invalid action:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_script', 'run_js_script');
```

The correct action is `wp_enqueue_scripts` (plural), not `wp_enqueue_script` (singular). Use this instead:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'run_js_script');
```

### Edit

Same problem here:

```
add_action('wp_register_script', 'register_script');
```

Just hook it into `wp_enqueue_scripts` for simplicity:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_script');
```

Actually, two better options:

1. Put your `wp_register_script()` call in the same `run_js_script` callback as your `wp_enqueue_script()` call.
2. Eliminate `wp_register_script()` call entirely, and just use the full parameters in `wp_enqueue_script()`.

Comment: I made that change and it still isn't working. Is there anything else I'm doing wrong here (I'm sure there is... Lol..)

Comment: Check all of your `add_action()` calls to ensure the action is correct. See edited answer.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the last part. You suggest adding the `wp_register_script()` in the same callback, but then say to completely eliminate it?

Comment: @Blaine, as I understand it, it's one ***or*** another.

Comment: Yes: either/or. You can just pass all the parameters to `wp_enqueue_script()`, and eliminate the `wp_register_script()` call entirely. You only need to separate them in the (rare?) case that you need to register a script *globally*, but only enqueue it *contextually*.